# How to create an array by reading a file in c++ if every line contains an integer?

Tags: c++, arrays, file

In C++ I should read a file in which every line contains an integer and transfer every integer into an array. I tried doing count the lines with getline() function. And created array however when I count the lines, it consumes and if I use getline() function again, it won't work. What should I do? Thank you.

```
ifstream inFile( fileName );
if ( inFile.is_open() ) {
    int size = 0;
    string line;
    while( getline(inFile, line)) 
         size++;
    int* array = new int [ size ];
    while ( getline( inFile, line )) {
         ....
    }
}
The code does not enter the second while.
```

Comment: You should add integers read to `std::vector`.

Comment: Please share the code that you're describing.

Comment: Edit the question, don't use comments. Also, make sure to post a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset fstream before second while loop

```
inFile.clear();
inFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
while ( getline( inFile, line )) {
....
```

Answer (score 0):

When this loop completes:

```
while( getline(inFile, line)) 
    // ...
```

the stream `inFile` has been exhausted, and there's no more data to read from it.

One option is to open the file again, and then read from it. However, this is wasteful, since you can keep track of the numbers you read from the file the first time:

```
std::vector<int> v;
int i;
while (inFile >> i)
  v.push_back(i);
```

Now you have all the numbers in a container, and you don't need to read from the file again.

Note that I'm using `std::vector` instead of an array, since it's much easier to work with.

If you *absolutely must* use an array, then you can read the file once to figure out how many integers are in the file:

```
int i, count = 0;
while (inFile >> i);
```

and then allocate memory for an array:

```
int *array = new int[count];
```

and then open the file again, and read into the array:

```
int i = 0;
while (inFile >> array[i++]);
```

Comment: There is no worry with the efficiency. However, I can not use vector in this assignment. Is there any other way I can use your idea?

Comment: @MustafaYaşar Added a solution using arrays as well.

Answer (score -1):

you can read the file into a string and then work with the string instead of with the file

```cpp
std::ifstream t("file.txt");
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << t.rdbuf();
std::string stringOfNumbers = buffer.str();
```

and from there split the string by the newline characters parse the split strings as ints